# Importing only postal codes for large number of contacts

Tags: contacts, cli

I'm trying to update a large list of zip codes.  Using the built-in updater, I have to break the files up repeatedly and it times out often.  I'm trying to learn to import from the command line, but can't seem to import with just a list of Contact IDs and Zip Codes.  This seems like the ideal way to match the zip codes to contacts but I get an error saying I have to include first_name, last_name, and email.  Is there a way to do this with just a CSV where one column is the Contact ID and the second column is the postal codes (and a third saying the 'contact_type')?

Comment: Have you tried the API CSV Importer extension at https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui

Comment: This is probably because Zip Codes are part of the address entity and not the contact entity so you would need the ID of the address. Taht being said teh API CSV importer may be a good choice as outlined by Andy.

Comment: how small are you having to break your files down to?